# Fail to comparison item_var against ansible_hostname

Tags: linux, ansible

I'm working with ansible version `2.9.13` and I'm trying to modify the following task -which btw is working fine - so I could **compare a list of given hostnames stored in a yml file against the fact `ansible_hostname`** before/while performing the create student operation.

The following is the `create_students` task fully working:

`create_a27_students.yml`

```
---
- hosts: a27-alumnes
  become: yes
  vars_files:
    - users/students.yml

  tasks:
  - import_tasks: tasks/create_students.yml
  - import_tasks: tasks/restart_lightdm.yml
```

`tasks/create_students.yml`

```
  - name: Create student's regular users
    user:
      name: "{{ item.name }}"
      # mkpasswd --method=sha-512
      password: "{{ item.pass | password_hash('sha512') }}"
      state: present
      shell: /bin/bash       # Defaults to /bin/bash
      system: no             # Defaults to no
      createhome: yes        # Defaults to yes
      home: /home/{{ item.name }}       # Defaults to /home/<username>
    with_items: "{{  students  }}"

  - import_tasks: restart_lightdm.yml
```

`tasks/restart_lightdm.yml`

```
  - name: Check if lightdm service exists (stat module)
    stat: path=/etc/init.d/lightdm
    register: service_stat

  - name: Check if lightdm service exists (service module)
    service: name=lightdm
    register: service

  - name: Restart lightdm service if exists and is running
    service: name=lightdm state=restarted
    when: service_stat.stat.exists and service.status.SubState == 'running'
    register: service_started
```

The following is the var file yml, `users/students.yml`:

```
---
    students:
        - name: smx
          pass: smx
          state: present

        - name: smx2
          pass: smx2
          state: present

        - name: arduino
          pass: arduino
          state: present
```

The following would be the list of hostnames, `data/hostnames.yml`:

```
---
    hostnames:
        - name: PC-a27-01
          hostname: PC-a27-01

        - name: PC-a27-01
          hostname: PC-a27-01

        - name: arduino
          hostname: arduino
```

The following would be the `create_students` task modified to run the comparison but it doesn't seem to work:

`create_a27_students.yml`

```
---
- hosts: a27-alumnes
  become: yes
  vars_files:
    - users/students.yml
    - data/hostnames.yml

  tasks:
  - import_tasks: tasks/create_students.yml
  - import_tasks: tasks/restart_lightdm.yml
```

`tasks/create_students.yml`

```
  - name: Create student's regular users
    user:
      name: "{{ item.name }}"
      # mkpasswd --method=sha-512
      password: "{{ item.pass | password_hash('sha512') }}"
      state: present
      shell: /bin/bash       # Defaults to /bin/bash
      system: no             # Defaults to no
      createhome: yes        # Defaults to yes
      home: /home/{{ item.name }}       # Defaults to /home/<username>
    ## I would also be interested on using the "in" condition as long as the "=="
    when: item.hostname == ansible_hostname
    with_items: "{{  students  }}", "{{ hostnames }}"

  - import_tasks: restart_lightdm.yml
```

Hope someone can help me to fix the issue.

Thanks,

PD: Here's [1] a copy of my github repo in case it helps

[1] https://github.com/pauperis/ansible/tree/master/playbooks

Answer (score 0):

hope this will be helpful.

First a comment, from Ansible 2.5, loop is the preferred syntax for iterations.
[Ansible Doc - Migrating from with_X to loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#migrating-from-with-x-to-loop)

So to my understanding you like to iterate over nested lists.
[Ansible Docs - Iterating over nested lists](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#iterating-over-nested-lists)

Notice that the list items will be `item.0` and `item.1`.
You you need to add the item index to your code as well `item.0.name`.

Following above example I think following would be something for you to elaborate around.
I just comment your previous line and add new line underneath.

```
  - name: Create student's regular users
    user:
      #name: "{{ item.name }}"
      name: "{{ item.0.name }}"
      # mkpasswd --method=sha-512
      #password: "{{ item.pass | password_hash('sha512') }}"
      password: "{{ item.0.pass | password_hash('sha512') }}"
      state: present
      shell: /bin/bash       # Defaults to /bin/bash
      system: no             # Defaults to no
      createhome: yes        # Defaults to yes
      #home: /home/{{ item.name }}       # Defaults to /home/<username>
      home: /home/{{ item.0.name }}       # Defaults to /home/<username>
    ## I would also be interested on using the "in" condition as long as the "=="
    #when: item.hostname == ansible_hostname
    when: item.1.hostname == ansible_hostname
    #with_items: "{{  students  }}", "{{ hostnames }}"
    loop: "{{ students|product(hostnames)|list }}"

  - import_tasks: restart_lightdm.yml
```